# Xamarin Forms - How to detect any gesture

Tags: xamarin.forms, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view in my Xamarin forms application where I need to detect if the user is interacting with the screen or not, and go back to the previous view afteer some time if there is no activity.

Is there a simple way to detect it from my ViewModel?

Otherwise, detecting the scrolling on a ListView can be enough. But the ListView has no "Scrolled" event... Maybe with a GestureRecognizer ?

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

This was interesting so I tried it on a project I am working on

I added this to the scrollview which contains all the views in my page but you can add it to any view you want:

```
<ScrollView.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HelpClickedCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</ScrollView.GestureRecognizers>
```

It's working fine and the command is fired when you tab on the screen but not when you swipe or scroll.

I think the new update of Xamarin will include the Swipe gesture but for now, many people implemented the swipe using pan gesture and some other simple gestures.

Here is a nice article I found with sample code in GitHub and I am sure that I found a nice example with all gestures. If I found it I will update you

[Gesture Recognizers with Xamarin.Forms](https://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/)